# Negative Array Indexing

Tags: c#, arrays, delphi

I have a piece of C# code represented like this

```
digitsResPtr[-1] = digitsPtr[0] << rightShiftRev;
```

where `digitsResPtr` and `digitsPtr` is a pointer to an array of UInt32 and `rightShiftRev` is an integer.

I want to know if this Delphi representation is correct?

```
(digitsResPtr - 1)^ := digitsPtr[0] shl rightShiftRev;
```

my major problem is the negative indexing.

Thanks.

Delphi XE7 UP 1.

Comment: we dont have negative indexes in c# in arrays. except if you write your own indexer.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary, thanks for replying but do remember i said digitsResPtr and digitsPtr are pointers to an array of UInt32 not arrays themselves.

Comment: @Xor-el And the reason why your C# code is using pointers is to in a way implement custom indexer. Now your main concern should be how your array is stored in the first place. For instance if you have Zero based array (first item has index 0) then trying to read item with index of -1 would actually result in reading of data that is out of array bounds. So most likely you would receive an Access Violation or EOutOfBound error if you have range checking enabled. So I suggest extreme caution. ...

Comment: ... Now if you are using static arrays (their size does not change during runtime) you can actually define an arrays whose first item has negative index like so `NegativeArray: Array[-5..10] of UInt32;` But you can not do this using dynamic arrays because all dynamic arrays in Delphi are Zero based.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's going to be cleanest to do this with pointer arithmetic. For instance

```
{$POINTERMATH ON}
....
(digitsResPtr - 1)^ := digitsPtr[0] shl rightShiftRev;
```

or

```
{$POINTERMATH ON}
....
digitsResPtr[-1] := digitsPtr[0] shl rightShiftRev;
```

I'm assuming that `digitsResPtr` has type `^UInt32` and points to somewhere in the middle of an array. In other words, you must have allocated arrays somehow or other and then initialised `digitsResPtr` something like this:

```
digitsResPtr := @digitsRes[5];
```

Comment: I have similar code in my BigInteger implementation. In that code, the equivalent of `digitsResPtr` is a running pointer (a `PUInt32`) into an array of `UInt32`.